# document.cookie doesn't see embedded expression in template literal

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, next.js, template-literals

I'm implementing logic for cookie consent with Next.js and Google Analytics 4 (gtag.js). I've used [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-analytics) example as basis. The logic is simple: if user accepted cookies - load script, if not - check if cookies were already present (e.g. user changed their mind) - disable GA cookies and delete current ones, if weren't present (first time consent) - just disable GA cookies.

GA4 [sets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookie-usage#gtagjs_google_analytics_4_-_cookie_usage) 3 cookies, one of which is -ga-(container-id). This ID should be stored as env var. To delete cookie I set Max-Age param to zero.

Code:

```
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (areCookiesAccepted) {
      console.log(1)
      const handleRouteChange = url => {
        gtag.pageview(url)
      }
      router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
      return () => {
        router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
      }
    } else {
      if (
        document.cookie.split(';').some(item => item.trim().startsWith('_ga=')) || 
        document.cookie.split(';').some(item => item.trim().startsWith(`_ga_${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID}=`)) || 
        document.cookie.split(';').some(item => item.trim().startsWith('_gid='))
      ) {
        console.log(2.1)
        window.gtag('consent', 'update', {'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied'})
        document.cookie = '_ga=; Max-Age=0;'
        document.cookie = `_ga_${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID}=; Max-Age=0;`
        document.cookie = '_gid=; Max-Age=0;'
      } else {
        console.log(2.2)
        window.gtag('consent', 'default', {'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied'})
      }
    }
  }, [router.events, areCookiesAccepted])
```

The problem is that document.cookie can't see embedded env var in template literal and cookie is not being deleted, but when I expose bare ID without env var - everything works okay. I double checked - no typos in env.local file. Does anybody knows what's wrong here?

Comment: So the `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID` env variable returns undefined on the browser?

Comment: I checked with console.log - it returns usual string as supposed to, but document.cookie doesn't see it. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

So far I ended up with hack. So this doesn't work:

```
document.cookie = `_ga_${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID}=; Max-Age=0;`
```

But this works:

```
const cookiePair = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('_ga_'))
const cookieName = cookiePair.substring(0, cookiePair.indexOf('='))
document.cookie = `${cookieName}=; Max-Age=0;`
```

Cookie is being deleted successfully. Still, I'm not fully satisfied with this approach and would like to know why initial problem happens.